# Filling no-data values while data mining

Tags: nan, missing-data, no-data

I am working on predictive maintenance and get temperature data from assets. In few months or few days asset remains down and we do not get temperature value. In this scenario i cannot fill data with missing value techniques. Also cannot give some number because even 0 and -1 are valid values for temperature. How to deal with such data?

I am thinking of putting very big value for such columns which is not possible as temperature.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me kindly edit with sufficient information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The value that you should put there *is* NA.

The data is missing, and must be treated as missing.

Even if you'd put an impossible value there (say, -10000 degrees, below absolute zero) this will cause *much* more havoc than properly encoding missing values as missing values (NA). There is no good reason to encore them as any other value, is there?